# CSS: why is only the first element not the same height?

Tags: css

Here: [URL](http://www.fipfip.com/symfony/web/app_dev.php/pizzas/partenaire/inscription) the first field is 40px high whereas all other ones are 30px. I don't get how it's possible.

I'd like:

- to correct & understand the problem
- make all the fields "vertical align" (the labels are not vertical centered).

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: The inputs are **30px high**. The `<input type="text/number">` containers are **40px high** because of those inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your second question, give the labels a `line-height` equal to the input next to it. You could also try:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
bottom: 50%;
line-height: 0;
```

for a more general style. Just apply it to `.labels` or something instead of individually styling each one.

Comment: Thank you! The only problem left is that it looks ugly on my `Nexus7`. Any idea how I could change the style to apply it `text-align: right;` only on normal screens (= not Mobiles or Tablets)?

Answer (score 0):

The following css from bootstrap adds 10px margin underneath your input:

```
select, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I removed stuff but 20px height plus 8px vertical padding, 2px for border, and 10px margin bottom means this will have 40px total overall height.

Override this style but add `margin: 0` for this particular element.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I've tried to apply jimjimmy1995's answer and it solved the 2nd problem, which was very important to me. Thank you again